# How to click a button while parsing web content

Tags: ios, swift, parsing, button, youtube

I am parsing YouTube in one of my apps. However, I want to click the "Load More" button at the bottom of the screen to get more results. Here is my current code:

```
let attemptedUrl = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCJFp8uSYCjXOMnkUyb3CQ3Q/videos")

    if let url = attemptedUrl {

        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            if let urlContent = data {

                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)

                //read and parse string

            }
       }
 }
```

How can I "click" the button while going through the content of the website? Thanks!

Comment: You want to know how to parse the HTML of the web page, find a load more button in that HTML, and generate a request that simulates the user having clicked that button?

Comment: @DuncanC Yes I would like to know how to find and click the "load more" button. However, I have already parsed the HTML of the site and downloaded the videos. Once the videos are loaded, I know how to get the videos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually search for a way to accomplish the same thing using URLSession like you but never found a working solution. What worked for me was using a hidden WKWebView that does all loading to to invoke buttons I would use the following code `webView.evaluateJavaScript("document.getElementById('buttonName').click")`